# How can I return all information (via IQueryable) regarding table that is connected to the foreign key in another table?

Tags: entity-framework, web-services, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api2

```
public IQueryable<Student> GetStudents()
{
    var balance = (from StandardX in db.Standards
                   join StudentX in db.Students
                   on StandardX.StandardId equals StudentX.StandardRefId
                   select new { StudentX.StudentID, StudentX.StudentName, StandardX.StandardName });

    return balance; // I can't handle that. how can I return? Please help.
}
```

***Question:***

I have two tables named respectively `standard` and `student`. I want to retrieve all student information via foreign key relationship. I searched everywhere regarding this topic but didn't find any suitable solution. Please help me with solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the relationship configured, try the include statement (assuming standard is the parent and 1:1, otherwise flip and/or add collection):

```
   var balance = (from StandardX std in db.Standards.Include("Student")
                  select new { std.Student.StudentID, std.Student.StudentName, std.StandardName });
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: thanks for your support my friend solved my problem it was very easy :D

Comment: only i should write  public IQueryable GetStudents() instead public IQueryable<Student> GetStudents().